# Flutter multidex problem With FirebaseAuth , Firestore and Google Sign in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin, flutter-dependencies

Flutter application is working fine if i use only firestore. But as now i want to add Firebase Auth it is Causing problem And showing 
[Dex error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmYK8.png)

How can i use both firestore and Firebase Auth.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your `app/build.gradle` file inside your `android` folder , add this attribute  `multiDexEnabled`.

```
         defaultConfig {
                ...
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
```

Don't forget:

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: Tried this one..
also the dependency too.

Comment: run: flutter clean and try again

Comment: if it doesn't work, please put your build.gradle file in the question.

Comment: FYI, as far as I understand, using multidex will limit your Android min sdk to 21. Below 21, the app will crash. Using version 0.7.3 should prevent the need for multidex, but there might be some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 4):

I did for this same error to make it work

```
multiDexEnabled true

dependencies {
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Answer (score 3):

Although having a `multiDexEnabled` true can solve the problem it will result in a `minSdkVersion 21` for your application because it will crash on all older devices than lollipop witch means losing millions of potential customers who still own this phones , right ??

**there is a  better solution**

just open your **App level build.gradle** and add these lines in place :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug{
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        
    }
```