# Adding multidex support to Flutter

Tags: error-handling, flutter, android-multidex

I am building my app with Flutter. Now I am always getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.* What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug',> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: ...The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.Learn how to resolve this issue: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html* Try:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 32s Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

So this error clearly says that I must add multidex-support. But how to do this in FLUTTER?

Comment: Check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?q=%22Execution+failed+for+task+%27%3Aapp%3AtransformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug%27%22&unscoped_q=%22Execution+failed+for+task+%27%3Aapp%3AtransformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug%27%22&type=Issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409800/10269042

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it with removing the CloudFirestore implementation. Seems there is a version bug at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Firebase or Firestore - Its the number of dependencies you have added to your application, you need to enable Multidex - there are some steps on how to do it online [Flutter multidex problem With FirebaseAuth , Firestore and Google Sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232452/flutter-multidex-problem-with-firebaseauth-firestore-and-google-sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can add the multidex support library to your project:

> dependencies {
> def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
> implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'
> }

To view the current versions for this library, see the information about Multidex on the versions page.

If you aren't using AndroidX, add the following support library dependency instead:

> dependencies {implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'}