# Not able to connect firebase to flutter application (android part)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter

In order to connect firebase to flutter on android I have executed the steps given in the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android .

And as soon as I open android/app/build.gradle my android studio shows an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'".

[Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException' error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA2L7.png)

[Error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXip8.png)

[Error message 1 continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRCoJ.png)

[Error message 1 ends here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HCQX.png)

Comment: Hi, Harsh! Can you check if this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232452/flutter-multidex-problem-with-firebaseauth-firestore-and-google-sign-in) is what you are after?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232452/flutter-multidex-problem-with-firebaseauth-firestore-and-google-sign-in

Comment: Got answer to my question at above link